# Authenticating basic-auth REST API calls from forms-authenticated web app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, cookies, asp.net-web-api

I'm developing a service that has two components - a **web interface** and a **REST API**. I use ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET Web API, respectively. The two components are hosted on *different subdomains of the same domain*.

I want the **REST API** to be used by both external users and the **web interface**, and I want to simplify authentication as much as possible.

The **REST API** currently only supports *basic authentication*.

The **web interface** uses *forms authentication* and thus generates an ASPXAUTH cookie. The **web interface** interacts with the **REST API** using AJAX calls.

My question to the community is:

> How do I authenticate the AJAX calls from the **web interface** to the
>   **REST API**, using the most elegant and secure method?

Some ideas:

- Send the ASPXAUTH cookie in the ajax calls (by changing the cookie domain to ".myservice.com" to allow cross-subdomain read) and adding an authentication method in the API that reads the ASPXAUTH. Not sure if this is a great idea, or how to implement this.
- Storing the user name and API key in separate cookies. Not really safe unless the values are encrypted/hashed.
- Using OAuth in the web interface and rest api, instead of forms + basic authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've come up with the following solution:

1. I've added form authentication to the **REST API** and made sure not to use `IsolateApps` in the `<machinekey>`section of *machine.config*. This ensures that the **REST API** can use the same `ASPXAUTH` cookie. I'm making sure to fall back to basic authentication if no `ASPXAUTH` cookie is present.
2. Since there's no way to include the `ASPXAUTH` cookie in ajax requests to a different subdomain due to the [Same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) (even though the cookie's domain is ".myservice.com"), the solution I chose was to add an application (through IIS) to the web interface with the name "api".
3. The ajax calls now point to "/app.myservice.com/api/..." instead of "https://api.myservice.com/...", and the `ASPXAUTH` cookie is included and works.

Not sure if this is the best solution, but it's both clean and secure. Only tweak is the sharing of machine keys. If running in a web farm you would need to set the same machine key to all machines.